# Как с помощью Keras строить нейронную сеть с несколькими выходными слоями для задач многоклассовой многозначной классификации?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow

Например, есть картинка, на которой изображены три элемента, первый элемент может принадлежать к одному из 100 классов, другой элемент к одному из 30 классов, третий к одному из 10 классов. Сначала с помощью

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(16, 3, padding = 'same', activation = 'elu', input_shape = (32, 32, 1)))
model.add(MaxPool2D())

model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, padding = 'same', activation = 'elu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D())

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(400, activation = 'elu'))
```

мы строим начало сверточной нейронной сети, и теперь хотим добавить к `dense`-слою три других слоя, каждый из которых будет задачу классификации для первого, второго и третьего элементов картинки. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во всяком случае, это лучше делать не через последовательную модель, а через функциональную:

```
  input_x = Input(X_train.shape[1:], name = 'inp')

  x = Dense(94, name = 'Dense_1')(input_x)
  x = LeakyReLU(name = 'LReLU_1')(x)
  x1 = Dropout(dropout_rate, name = 'Dp_1')(x)
  x2 = Dense(67, name = 'Dense_2')(x1)
  x2 = LeakyReLU(name = 'LReLU_2')(x2)
  x3 = Dense(60, name = 'Dense_2')(x1)
  x3 = LeakyReLU(name = 'LReLU_2')(x3)
  x = concatenate(x2, x3)
  x = Dropout(dropout_rate, name = 'Dp_2')(x)
  x = Dense(1, name = 'Dense_3')(x)
  x = LeakyReLU(name = 'LReLU_3')(x)

  model = Model((input_x), x)
```

В середине я сделал разветвление на ветки x2 x3, потом объединил их. А можно не объединять, подавать на разные выходы. У меня таких задач пока не было, но читал, что градиент по обучению всё же делают на один выход, и возможно модель придётся разбивать с помощью layers, output, и обучать отдельно разные выходы, возможно фиксируя веса с помощью trainable. Старайтесь чётче представить свою задачу. Желаю успеха в поисках.